# How do I hide keyboard programmatically with java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-development

I am trying to hide a numbers keyboard programmatically with java and I used this code in a `onClick` of a button

```
 ​        ​InputMethodManager​ inputMethodManager ​=​(​InputMethodManager​)getSystemService(​Activity​.​INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE​); 
 ​        inputMethodManager​.​hideSoftInputFromWindow(view​.​getWindowToken(), ​0​);
```

But as a result when the user click the first time the numbers keyboard become strings keyboard (normal keyboard) and when the user click the 2nd time the keyboard hides.
I want the keyboard get hide from the first click, any help ?

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for hiding keyboard:

```
/*--for hiding keyboard on click--*/
InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
View view3=getCurrentFocus();
//If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
if (view3==null){
    view3=new View(this);
}
assert imm != null;
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view3.getWindowToken(), 0);
```